# Update a column by selecting random value from a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure

```
+----+---+
| A  | B | 
+----+---+
|  1 |   |
|  2 |   |
|  3 |   |
|  4 |   |
|  5 |   |
|  6 |   | 
+----+---+
```

I need to update the column `B` by selecting any of the element randomly from column `A`.

I used the query to get a random value from column `A`.

```
SELECT A FROM
( SELECT A FROM MyTable
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Then I tried this query to update the value `B`

```
UPDATE MyTable SET B=( SELECT A FROM
( SELECT A FROM MyTable
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1);
```

But this will set all the rows with same value. But I need each row to be set with random values.

How can I achieve this in `Oracle 11g`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the query you are trying:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET B = (SELECT A
             FROM (SELECT A FROM MyTable ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
             WHERE rownum = 1
            );
```

I think the problem is that the optimizer is too smart -- it sees the subquery and executes it just once.  In other databases, this can be fixed by using a correlation clause.  But, Oracle does not allow that in subqueries nested more than one level.

So, here is a slightly different formulation:

```
UPDATE MyTable t
    SET B = (SELECT MAX(A) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
             FROM MyTable t2
             WHERE t2.A <> t.A  -- This is an arbitrary correlation clause to ensure that the subquery runs for each row
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table Random_numbers;

create table random_numbers (
Product_code                     VARCHAR2(40),  
Item_code                     VARCHAR2(40) 
);

insert into random_numbers(Product_code) values(1);
insert into random_numbers(Product_code) values(2);
insert into random_numbers(Product_code) values(3);

insert into RANDOM_NUMBERS
(ITEM_CODE) 
select RANDOM_NUMBERS.PRODUCT_CODE from RANDOM_NUMBERS ORDER BY
                dbms_random.value;
```

I think this will help you.
output:

```
+-----------+-------------+
|ITEM_CODE  | Product_code|
|1          |  2          |
|2          |  3          |
|3          |  1          |
+-----------+-------------+
```